# Bind Error in launching SNMP4J Sample Agent

Tags: network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, opennms

I am trying to run the sample [SNMP agent](https://oosnmp.net/dist/release/org/snmp4j/snmp4j-agent/2.4.0/snmp4j-agent-2.4.0-distribution.zip) ("SampleAgent.java") which ships with the **[SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/)** library.
 It runs fine on address 127.0.0.1:4700.
But
My aim is to see this agent reply to [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/)'s getRequests, thus I tried running it on Port **161**(SNMP).
 But it crashed with **bind** error. 
My assumption was it may be conflicting with the default **net-snmp** agent on the Ubuntu distro. Thus I tried running the agent on a **Windows7** PC after **uninstalling** SNMP client.
 **Crash !!** 
Now at last I tried to run it on a live-iso of Ubuntu 15.04, which I assume did not run the SNMP agent, but still got the same error.
Someone please help me figuring out what may be going wrong ??
[image: Run Configurations]

Here is the error on the IntelliJ console.
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

OpenNMS `snmp-config.xml` file allows it to connect to an agent that is listening on a non-default port, i.e. not 161.

See http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Data_Collection_Configuration_How-To#snmp-config.xml

```
<snmp-config retry="3" timeout="800" read-community="public" write-community="private">

      // SNIP ...

     <definition port="4700">
          <specific>192.168.5.50</specific>
     </definition>

</snmp-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! It ran on Live-iso of Ubuntu upon running as **root**.

Comment: Does it mean I need to uninstall/purge the snmpd on whichever linux PC I need to run this client ?? ( on port 161)

Comment: Any port number smaller than 1024 requires root permission to monitor. That's why it failed. To run snmp4j agent along with net-SNMP agent, you might refer to related documentation of how to configure subagent.